# What would happen if React doesn't auto bind instance methods for you in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind

Learning [React](http://jamesknelson.com/learn-raw-react-ridiculously-simple-forms/) and seeing the below code I read that React auto binds for you so the `this`s in 1 and 2 work out well. I was wondering what would the `this` in each one refer to if React didn't auto bind it for you? Wouldn't the 2 `this` refer tot he `input` element and thus not be able to get to the 1 `this`?

```
var ContactForm = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    // ...
  },

  onNameInput: function(e) {
    //1
    this.props.onChange(Object.assign({}, this.props.value, {name: e.target.value}))
  },

  render: function() {
    return React.createElement('form', {className: 'ContactForm'},
      React.createElement('input', {
        // ...
        //2
        onInput: this.onNameInput,
      })
      // ...
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: I would replace the `1` and `2` with comments. Right now that's invalid code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out for yourself by seeing what this component will do when you extend `React.Component` instead of using `createClass({})`.

That said, this is really just a JS question. `this` points to different things depending on how its used. If auto-binding did not take place in the above example, then it would most likely refer to `window`, if you were running React in the browser. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for more details.

> Wouldn't the 2 this refer tot he input element and thus not be able to get to the 1 this?

`this` #2 is in the scope of its surrounding function, specifically the `render` function. It points to whatever the `this` scope of that function is, which in this case is the component instance. During the assignment `onInput: this.onNameInput`, you are dereferencing `onNameInput` from the component instance, so when you make that assignment, it may no longer be bound to that instance. If `onNameInput` was never bound, when it is called its `this` will be `window`.

Comment: So when I replaced the 2nd `this.onNameInput` with a `function(){console.log(this)}`, it logged the window. How does React then know to have `this` refer to the component instance to look for a method with `this.onNameInput` and at the window when it's just `this`?

Comment: `function(){console.log(this)}` is never bound to that React component instance, so `this` will always be `window` when that function is called. I stress, though, that this has nothing to do with React and is a general JS question.

Comment: Yeah, I would read more about `this`, and most importantly, play with it, until you are satisfied you understand how it behaves. It's a strange part of JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Is the reason that `function(){console.log(this)}` is never bound to that React component instance because it's a anonymous function? So even though `onNameInput` calls this anonymous function, the caller of the console.log is not `onNameInput`, but the anonymous function itself, so that's why `this` refers to window object?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's because it's anonymous. Rather, it is because `this` inside a function is bound to the global scope unless the function is invoked with `new` or called with `.call()` or `.apply()` or is the product of binding with `.bind()`.

Comment: Try `(function(){console.log(this)}).bind('a')()`, for example. Run that in your console. It's the same as `(function(){console.log(this)}).call('a')` and `(function(){console.log(this)}).apply('a', [])`

Comment: I thought if you have an object `var a = {f:function(){console.log(this)}}`, then if you call `a.f()` you will get back the object `a` not the global window even without binding because the caller of `f` is `a`. In the same sense, shouldn't I get back the input element for `this` if I replaced the 2nd `this.onNameInput` with a `function(){console.log(this)}`?

Comment: "In the same sense, shouldn't I get back the input element for this if I replaced the 2nd this.onNameInput with a function(){console.log(this)}?" — Nope, because `this` in that function is not scoped lexically (meaning set to the this value of the enclosing execution context) but, rather, its value depends on how the function is called. Since it's not called with `call` or `apply` or from an object, `this` will be global.

Comment: When you call a function directly from an object, as with `a.f()`, that function's home is that object. But once you assign that function to a variable, you can think of it as homeless. It's no longer bound to that object or any other object, unless you've explicitly permanently bound it, Before `Function.prototype.bind` was widely supported, people would implement it themselves in libraries like underscore and lodash and the implementation would look like `function bind(fn, target) { return function() { fn.apply(target, arguments) }; }`. That's really all "binding" is.

Comment: When you talk about "auto binding' in React, that means the base constructor for React components looks through all the functions on its prototype and replaces them with bound versions, so you can pass those functions around and not worry about permanently binding them yourself.